# htaccess - How to account for space characters when using literal notation?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

If I have a url `root.com/index rel` which gets encoded to `root.com/index%20rel` how do I target it using htaccess literal notation?

`=` denotes literal nation.
So I do something like this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =index rel
RewriteRule .* / [L,R=302,]
```

But htaccess thinks the space makes things an extra prameter rather than a part of the same parameter.

Escaping doesn't seem to work

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23060414/allow-space-in-htaccess-url-redirect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using a lexicographical/literal comparison (ie. `=` operator) you can surround the entire *CondPattern* in double quotes if the string contains a space. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "=index rel"
```

(The `REQUEST_URI` variable is already percent-decoded.)

However, that condition still won't match, since the `REQUEST_URI` variable starts with a slash (unlike the URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern*). So, you would need:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "=/index rel"
```

But, as Unbeliever suggests, if possible you should be matching this URL-path in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* instead (which you could also surround in double quotes if you prefer that syntax). The `RewriteRule` pattern is processed first, so it is more efficient to do what you can there, rather than match the URL-path in a *condition*.

---

**UPDATE:** Working example tested on Apache 2.2 (Windows and Linux) and Apache 2.4 (Windows):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "=/foo bar"
RewriteRule ^ /baz [R=302,L]
```

A request for `/foo%20bar` is redirected to `/baz`.

Comment: do you have a working example? My first though was to use quotes as well, but I could not get it to work :-( I get a 400 return code, "RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters", using either single or double quotes, with the '=' inside or outside the quotes. I'd be really interested to know.

Comment: I've added a working example to my answer (pretty much the same as the earlier example). You should be able to use double quotes to surround any parameter (even the flags - which could then contain spaces - not that that would be recommended! :). A 400 would be a strange response code here? If you were getting a "RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters" (ie. syntactically invalid) you would expect a 500 error?

Comment: Arg! Was user error on my part (as usual!) had %2 instead of %20 in the URL I was requesting. Thanks. I agree the error about the rewritecond flags in the apache log is a bit strange, though the 400 code is not

Comment: I'm curious if `"=stuff  asdf"` would work with `Redirect` as well.

Comment: @ahnbizcad You can use double quotes to surround mod_alias `Redirect` parameters as well (in fact, you can use double quotes with most Apache directives). However, `Redirect` (or `RedirectMatch`) does not support the lexicographical comparison operators (`=`, `>`, `<`, etc.) - that's a mod_rewrite feature.

Comment: Note: once double quotes are introduced, it changes what characters need to be escaped. `\"` at the very least.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you cannot have a space in the target pattern when using lexical comparisons (as opposed to PCRE) since I think the "escaping" is something PCRE interprets. Also you do not need a `RewriteCond` since a `RewriteRule` matches against the request URI. Use the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^index\ rel$ / [L,R=302]
```

Comment: i just havent had luck getting the rewrite rule first argument to test the uri when i also have a rewritecond query param

Comment: Well if you have further queries you'll need to post the details. If you're going to do much mod_rewrite I'd spend some time learning how to use the RewriteLog